# Terraform moved several element at once

Tags: terraform

I'm using the terraform `moved` block to replace some resources without destroying/recreating them.

It's a list of resources, and for now, the only way I found to replace is using several `moved` blocks

```
moved {
  from = null_resource.default[0]
  to = null_resource.default["0"]
}

moved {
  from = null_resource.default[1]
  to = null_resource.default["1"]
}

moved {
  from = null_resource.default[2]
  to = null_resource.default["2"]
}

...

moved {
  from = null_resource.default[20]
  to = null_resource.default["20"]
}
```

Even if it works well, I'm almost sure it's not the most optimized way. I have 20 resources to replace and it's just 20 times copy/paste.

Is there a way to do that in a smarter way? using a loop for example

Thanks

Comment: You can create some script, that will parse your TF code, and outputs new version of your scripts with replicated `move` blocks.

Comment: Yes but at the end the tf file will still have all these blocks

Comment: Is this just one example, because you really do not need to do this for `null_resource`?

Comment: Of course, it's just an example here. But the idea remains the same. I would like to use something like `for_each`  inside the `moved` block for example

Comment: The design of of `moved` blocks is to clearly define each individual change. There isn't currently any means to define a "rule" for moving lots of resource instances all at once. You can generate `moved` blocks using a script as Marcin suggested, but however you do it there will always need to be one `moved` block for each resource instance you want to move.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your full use case, but in cases where resources being moved are not part of a shared module so they are only present in a small number of states then it may be better to use classic method with the CLI to move the resources. `terraform state mv {from} {to}`

Another option would be, if you are not changing the keys of the resource id then you don't have to specify each key individually.

```
moved {
  from = null_resource.default
  to = null_resource.default_new
}
```

In your example however you are changing the key type from a number to a string. So if that is required this will not be as helpful.

The moved blocks are a great tool and very helpful with shared modules, but it does have this limitation. I would also very much like to see `for_each` support added to the moved block.

Comment: I'm ashamed. Down voted as I thought this resulted in an error but it was due to unrelated bug on my end. Sadly vote is locked and I can no longer undo but this would get my upvote.